# Solve this set theory question using venn-diagram?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

If $A$ and $B$ are given sets then prove using venn diagram that, $A \cap (A \cap B)^C=A \cap B^C$.
Note-:
I tried solving but I got $A \cap (A \cap B)^C =A$ (wrong), using the venn diagram.

Comment: Have you tried yourself? Where did you get stuck or go wrong? What did your attempt look like?

Comment: You've probably forgotten to use two different shades for $A$ and for $(A\cap B)^c$, thus ending up with the whole $A$ instead of the part you wanted.

Comment: Please can you illustrate using venn-diagram, I have done the same thing that you have written i.e ending the whole with A instead of what was required. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend translating the question into predicate logic. It reveals the core ideas very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could do:

[image]

The left circle is $A$, and the right circle is $B$. The horizontal stripes is $A$, and the vertical stripes is $(A \cap B)^C$.  So, you see that the only area where you have both horizontal and vertical stripes is $A \cap B^C$

(I used Powerpoint to do this ... I wanted to use transparent colors, but Paint does not seem to have transparent colors, and in Powerpoint I can't seem to apply Fill to intersections of object ... if anyone knows how to do this nicely I'd be happy to hear about it!)

Comment: Thanks, it helped!

Comment: @TeamB.I Great, glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using demorgan's law followed by the distributive law:
$A \cap (A\cap B)^c \equiv A \cap (A^c \cup B^c) \equiv (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B^c) \equiv A\cap B^c$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that by [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and distributive law
$$A \cap (A \cap B)^c=A \cap (A^c \cup B^c)=(A \cap A^c) \cup (A\cap B^c).$$
By using Venn diagrams, compare the above set with $A \cap B^c$.